# Convert callback to RX.Observable in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am working on a project that is using a third-party library that cannot be swapped out. It essentially goes out to a URL source and returns data. It **does not** return a promise. It passes the returned data back to an anonymous callback...Not one you pass to the function.

The documentation is spotty, but here is how they instruct you to use their library.

```
third-party(URLsource, selector, scope)(function(err, data){ /* work with data array here*/ });
```

Currently, the code is a mess. This is partly do to callback hell, and over-use of promises.

Piping the data through observables would help streamline and clean up this project a lot....But I'm still learning RXjs and just how observables work.

I thought this problem would be a good candidate for:

```
let datapull = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(third-party);
let result = datapull(URLsource, selector, scope);
result.subscribe(result => console.log(result), e => console.log("Error: " + e)
```

However, this doesn't work because the last parameter of:

```
third-party(URLsource, selector, scope)
```

is not callback function.

How do I wrap the results from this third-party function in an RX Observable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage example suggests that the third-party API function returns a function that takes a callback.

If that's the case, it's the result of the third-party call that needs to be passed to `bindNodeCallback`, not the function itself:

```
let datapull = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(thirdParty(URLsource, selector, scope));
let result = datapull();
result.subscribe(result => console.log(result), e => console.log("Error: " + e)
```

Comment: Ugh...this is so obvious now. Thanks for the help!